# catch undefiended value doesn't work with JS

Tags: javascript

I `console.log(myVar)`, I saw undefined so I do

```
if(myVar == 'undefined') alert('undefined)
```

but the alert doesn't pop up, what's the problem? how to catch undefined in javascript?

Comment: use `if(typeof myVar == 'undefined')`

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot the `'` to end the string you pass to `alert`
2. You are comparing the value `myVar` to the string `'undefined'`. You need to either compare the `typeof` the variable or you need to compare to the value `undefined`